# How to exclude method from CXF WebService - strange behavior

Tags: java, cxf, java-ws

Can someone explain to me the following behavior of CXF?

I have simple WebService:

```java
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

public interface MyWebService {

    @WebMethod
    String method1(String s);

    @WebMethod
    String method2(String s);

    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    String methodToExclude(String s);

}
```

I want to have my `methodToExclude` in interface (for Spring), but I do not want to have this method in generated WSDL file. The code above does exactly that.

But when I add `@WebService` annotation to the interface I get error:

```java
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface MyWebService {

    @WebMethod
    String method1(String s);

    @WebMethod
    String method2(String s);

    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    String methodToExclude(String s);

}
```

> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsConfigurationException: The @javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true) cannot be used on a service endpoint interface. Method: methodToExclude

Can someone explain this to me? What's the difference? Also I'm not sure if it will work fine later, but I didn't find the way how to exclude the `methodToExclude` when I use `@WebService`.

Answer (score 7):

The @javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true) is used on the implementation:

```
public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebService {
    ...
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    String methodToExclude(String s) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Don´t include the method methodToExclude in the interface:

```
@WebService
public interface MyWebService {
    @WebMethod
    String method1(String s);

    @WebMethod
    String method2(String s);

}
```

Comment: @Betlista cannot afford to take out methodToExclude from the interface to satisfy Spring, all he needs to do is to include `@WebMethod(exclude = true)` in implementation only.

Answer (score 2):

Its late but I would like to chip in my answer.

1. Get rid of all the **@WebMethod** as they are optional and needed only when a method must be excluded.

   ```
   import javax.jws.WebMethod;
   import javax.jws.WebService;

   @WebService
   public interface MyWebService {

     String method1(String s);

     String method2(String s);

     String methodToExclude(String s);

   }
   ```
2. Add @WebMethod(exclude = true) to Interface Implementation only

   ```
   public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebService {

     String method1(String s) {
       // ...
     }

     String method2(String s) {
       // ...
     }

     @WebMethod(exclude = true)
     String methodToExclude(String s) {
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```